# Reactjs voicenote component with the ability to delete and remake

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a reactjs component that will handle voice note recordings. I've tried using a vanilla js approach - but I need to take out the constructor and re-apply the functions from within the component itself.

Also how would I create a wave visualisation - of the voice note for playback so its more like this - with the ability of deleting it and starting again.
[image]

https://codepen.io/winrey/pen/xvxrxR

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-haze-gzwthj
current code base

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import parse from 'html-react-parser';

import './VoiceNote.scss';

class VoiceNote extends Component {

  //https://codepen.io/winrey/pen/xvxrxR
  render() {    
/*
            class VoiceRecorder {
                constructor() {
                    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                        console.log("getUserMedia supported")
                    } else {
                        console.log("getUserMedia is not supported on your browser!")
                    }

                    this.mediaRecorder = ""
                    this.stream = ""
                    this.chunks = []
                    this.isRecording = false

                    this.recorderRef = document.querySelector("#recorder")
                    this.playerRef = document.querySelector("#player")
                    this.startRef = document.querySelector("#start")
                    this.stopRef = document.querySelector("#stop")
                    
                    this.startRef.onclick = this.startRecording.bind(this)
                    this.stopRef.onclick = this.stopRecording.bind(this)

                    this.constraints = {
                        audio: true,
                        video: false
                    }
                    
                }

                handleSuccess(stream) {
                    this.stream = stream
                    this.stream.oninactive = () => {
                        console.log("Stream ended!")
                    };
                    this.recorderRef.srcObject = this.stream
                    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream)
                    console.log(this.mediaRecorder)
                    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.onMediaRecorderDataAvailable.bind(this)
                    this.mediaRecorder.onstop = this.onMediaRecorderStop.bind(this)
                    this.recorderRef.play()
                    this.mediaRecorder.start()
                }

                handleError(error) {
                    console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error)
                }
                
                onMediaRecorderDataAvailable(e) { this.chunks.push(e.data) }
                
                onMediaRecorderStop(e) { 
                        const blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { 'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' })
                        const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                        this.playerRef.src = audioURL
                        this.chunks = []
                        this.stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())
                        this.stream = null
                }

                startRecording() {
                    if (this.isRecording) return
                    this.isRecording = true
                    this.startRef.innerHTML = 'Recording...'
                    this.playerRef.src = ''
                    navigator.mediaDevices
                        .getUserMedia(this.constraints)
                        .then(this.handleSuccess.bind(this))
                        .catch(this.handleError.bind(this))
                }
                
                stopRecording() {
                    if (!this.isRecording) return
                    this.isRecording = false
                    this.startRef.innerHTML = 'Record'
                    this.recorderRef.pause()
                    this.mediaRecorder.stop()
                }
                
            }

            window.voiceRecorder = new VoiceRecorder()
*/


    return (
      <div className={"voice-note "}>

        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                VoiceNote
                                <span>Recorder</span>
                                <audio id="recorder" muted hidden></audio>
                                <div>
                                    <button id="start">Record</button>
                                    <button id="stop">Stop Recording</button>
                                </div>
                                <span>Saved Recording</span>
                                <audio id="player" controls></audio>

              </Grid>
           
        </Grid>
      
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default VoiceNote;
```